# Cannot convert value of type 'UIColor' to expected argument type 'NSCoder' and Extra argument 'size' in call

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

```
import UIKit

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
                navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
                
                navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

       
    }
    
    func addNavBar(_ color: UIColor) {
          
            let size = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 91)
        let navImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(size: size, color: color)) 
            view.addSubview(navImageView)
```

How can I fix this? Thank you guys.

Comment: Did you declare a `UIImage.init(size:color:)` initialiser anywhere? If not, why did you expect `UIImage(size: size, color: color)` to work?